# PS3 Save runs very slow on PC

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, ps3

I've always played Skyrim on PS3 but now I'm moving to PC, so I've taken the save form the console and put it on my computer.

The problem is that when it loads, it's completely lagged, it takes seconds to move for example.

In my PS3 I have the normal Skyrim with the 3 DLC's installed and in the PC i have the Legendary Edition, perhaps that's the problem.

Anyway, if I disable Dragonborn DLC it remains the same, the same happens if I disable Hearthfire, but when I disable Dawnguard it runs fine. If I turn on DragonBorn and Hearthfire it remains running fine, but if I change the scenario (fast travel or entering a building) the game crashes and closes (The same happens if I only set Dawnguard enabled)

I tried installing Skyrim Script Extender and I didn't manage to get it working.

I installed all four "Unnofficial" Skyrim Patches from Nexus Mods and nothing happened.

I don't really know what can be happening, becouse I started a new game (and advanced in the game as well) and it works just fine.

Anyone know anything about it?

Comment: If you start a new game on PC, does the problem still occur? If so, it's unrelated to the save file, and probably to do with your computer. What's the specs of your PC?

Comment: @Robotnik Hi, as I mentioned I did start a new game and everything works just fine, in fact im playing that save right now.

Comment: Hmm. The only advice I can give comes from the Fallout world (they run on the same engine). When disabling a DLC/mod, stand inside (say, your house) and 'Wait' for 7 in-game days. This resets all areas (monsters will respawn, items will be back in place etc), the important thing being it removes references to the missing DLC items/quest points/monsters etc.

Comment: @Robotnik Ok but I dont want to remove a mod or anything. Are you saying to load the save and wait 7 days?

Comment: Is there a 'wait' function in Skyrim? it should allow you to set an amount of hours to wait. Do 7 lots of '24 hours' to wait 7 days. Again, I'm assuming from what I know of Fallout, I've never played Skyrim sorry

Comment: @Robotnik Yes there is, I will try that and tell you what happened, thanks.

Comment: @Robotnik OK so I waited TWO MONTHS of game days and everything is the same D: I dont know, may be the save is too big or there is a compatibility problem :'(

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. It was a long shot :/. Unfortunately that's all I've got. I dunno if it's a compatibility problem... I mean it could be but I honestly don't know. What happens if you start a *new* game on the PS3, and transfer it over?

Comment: Try using save cleaner tools, such as [Save Cleaner](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31724/?) and [Save game script cleaner](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52363/?) (I suggest both) I've never used them, but they have enough endorsements to be viable to try. I suggest loading the save and saving right afterwards, so the save was actually created by the PC version as an added precaution.

Comment: @MrLemon Thank you for the answer. I tried both tools and they didnt work. A shame. But thanks anyway :D